# Variable or Signal Needed?

Tags: variables, signals, vhdl

So I am designing a serial squarer. My program takes a basic binary counter, and uses each count of the counter to calculate squares in series. When I try to synthesize my code, depending on how I arrange my code, either synthesis runs almost infinitely, or the synthesis run just crashes entirely. So I figured that I cannot update my signal `r_final => r_final + r_min1` because I remember that not being a thing in vhdl. So I have decided that I need to set `r_final` to a variable instead of a signal. I'm not sure how I should declare `r_final` as a variable. Can anyone provide some insight on how I can get `r_final` to update with itself?

This is my main code, the part in question is under the comment -- next state logic:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity serial_square is
    port(
    clk, reset: in std_logic;
    q: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0));
end serial_square;

architecture behavioral of serial_square is
    signal r_reg : unsigned (3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal r_next : unsigned (3 downto 0);
    signal r_2i : unsigned (3 downto 0); 
    signal r_min1 : unsigned (3 downto 0);
    shared variable r_final : unsigned := "0000";

begin
-- register
    process(clk,reset)
    begin
        if (reset='1') then
            r_reg <= (others => '1');
        elsif (clk'event and clk='1') then 
            r_reg <= r_final;
            end if;
    end process;
        -- next state logic
        r_next <= r_reg +1; -- r_reg + 1
        r_2i <= r_next(2 downto 0) & '0'; -- multiply by 2
        r_min1 <= r_2i - 1; -- minus one
        r_final := r_min1 + r_final; -- add r_min1 to r_final, output should be the count r_next, squared.
        --output logic
        q <= std_logic_vector(r_reg);
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0):

The update of `r_final` must be in the clocked process, so the next value is generated through a synchronous (clocked) update, since this is the structure that matches the available hardware.

Shared variables can't be synthesized, but is a feature only used for test benches.

Comment: So If I move the update of `r_final` to under `r_reg <= r_final`, then will my code still act as I want it to? And is `r_final` a signal or a variable in your case?

Comment: I suggest that `r_final` should be a signal, but it can actually also be a process variable, but don't make it a shared variable.  You can verify the behavior in a simulation, and depending on the requirement specification at the cycle level, it you may need to assign `r_reg <= r_final + r_min1`